# Show input fields with Jquery on multiple places

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, select, input

I'm having an order form with 6 steps, by hidden div's. Every input field en selectfields having there own ID.

All the values have to show 1 time, except for the select with ID: catid, this one has to show up on every page. But with the code below it's only showing in one div.

Can anyone help me?

With this jquery i'm showing all the values on the last stap, sort of summary.

```
<script>
$("text1preview").draggable({ containment: '#dragcontainer' });
$("address1preview").draggable({ containment: '#dragcontainer' });
$("titlepreview").draggable({ containment: '#dragcontainer' });
$("zipcodepreview").draggable({ containment: '#dragcontainer' });
$("descriptionpreview").draggable({ containment: '#dragcontainer' });
$("wijkpreview").draggable({ containment: '#dragcontainer' });
$("address2preview").draggable({ containment: '#dragcontainer' });
$("tagspreview").draggable({ containment: '#dragcontainer' });
$("catidpreview").draggable({ containment: '#dragcontainer' });
$("pricepreview").draggable({ containment: '#dragcontainer' });
</script>
```

Comment: A jsfiddle or other example with your css and html would really help us.

Comment: Txh dave, i'm got a little further now, I'm now getting the value from the select option that i wanted. Now the only problem is that i'm not getting the value printed in multiple div's. It is just showing up in the first div with the id:. This is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/fJdmz/1/

Comment: you shouldn't have duplicate ids on your elements, you should set a common class name on the divs and use a class selector to set the value

Comment: thx dave, but i not really understand what you are saying.. :( can you help me a little more?

Comment: have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/davidoleary/cTDvd/ I've updated your example

Comment: Thank you, this is really great. I'm facing another, but last problem i see. The value 62 is from the cms, but in de div it has to show the name: 'huurwoning' Can you give me an hint where and how to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the selected text value you can use jQuerys .text(); shown in the example below

```
$("#myselect :selected").text();
```

Updated example:
http://jsfiddle.net/davidoleary/cTDvd/2/

Comment: Works like a charm :) thank you!! 
Now i notice that my Google Maps isn't working, because i'm using: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

But when i'm deleting this rule, the div's not working anymore :(

Comment: That is because its not the google maps JavaScript, it is the jQuery library, when you removed it you stopped jQuery from working. look at the url :)

Comment: Yes, thats right, but maps was working correct until i added the code below, but when i remove the scr the div's not working anymore, but maps is visible again. Is there a way to let them work all?

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#catid").change(function() {
var src = $(this).val();
    $(".categoryid").html($(this).find(":selected").text());
});
});  </script>

Comment: can you create a fiddle of the example? - it may be worth creating a seperate question for this

Comment: is it caused by the script block around $(document).ready(function() is not closed?

Comment: no, but it is closed now :) unfortunality it isn't it. unfortunately it was not the problem..

Comment: is'nt there a part of the .js file that i'm needing for the divs to work correctly that i can include in the page you think?

Comment: you should only need jquery and the code in the fiddle i posted. I cant say anything else without seeing the problem

Comment: Hmm.. thats not so nice :) it is hard for me to create a fiddle, because it is a large site, with a lot of includes, so i cannot recreate the map problem :(

Comment: Being honest, I'd close this question, because we addressed the first is two problems, then create a new question with your javascript and html/ fiddle if possible. there should be no reason the map and the select should not work together, there is something small wrong that i cant help with cause i cant see your code.

Comment: Thank you! I'm making a new question. Thank you for the help, it save me a few hours of searching :)